# Exporting With 300ppi and Maintaining Art Board Size in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, resolution

When I start a new document, I input the size that I need for the final project. When I have been exporting my work, in 300 ppi, the final product ends up with dimensions far larger than my original art board.

The work that I do is to be displayed on 4K monitors and needs to maintain a very clear, loss-less quality, but it is also imperative that it remains the same size I noted when starting the project.

How can I go about exporting my work so that it is both 300ppi and the dimensions I set for the art board?

Answer (score 0):

> When I start a new document, I input the size that I need for the final project.

For the final part of your question you need to use pixels as units.

> When I have been exporting my work, in 300 ppi...

So you need a printed work? you use ppi. If it is for screen  like it seems to be you do not need 300 ppi at all, but absolute pixel dimensions.

> needs to maintain a very clear, loss-less quality

If you work with a metholology and process you do not "loose" quality, you mantain a quality process.

> How can I go about exporting my work so that it is both 300ppi and the dimensions I set for the art board?

You do not need "both" as I explained above. There is a chance Ilustrator feels that you need 72 or 96 ppi. It is a interpretation of the creators of ilustrator, but try that.